# I would like to expand a SQL query to also get the name of the ID's it is selecting. How do I do that?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

At the moment I have a very basic SQL query, however I would like to expand it in order to fetch the names of the ID's it is referencing as well. The problem is, it's a Parent > Child relationship table. The Parent and Children items are part of the same table, but different rows.

```
    $GetRelations = "
    SELECT RelationUID, BlockTypeUID, ChildBlockUID, Weight FROM block_type_relations
    WHERE BlockTypeUID = '$BlockTypeUID'
    ";
```

When I only have a single BlockTypeUID to initially fetch the records, how can I shift this query around so that it also fetches the names from table block_types for both BlockTypeUID and ChildBlockUID? I'm writing this in mySQLi.

Comment: If I understand what you are after correctly, it sounds like you need to join in the block_types table.  Or, do a sub-select (which might be easier to manage because you'd be referencing the table more than once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name is in a column named "name", the query could look like this

```
$GetRelations = "
SELECT a.RelationUID, a.BlockTypeUID, a.ChildBlockUID, a.Weight 
    b.NAME AS BlockTypeName, c.NAME AS ChildBlockName
FROM block_type_relations a
INNER JOIN block_types b ON b.ID = a.BlockTypeUID
INNER JOIN block_types c ON c.ID = a.CildBlockUID
WHERE a.BlockTypeUID = '$BlockTypeUID'
";
```

Comment: This actually works best. I did have to modify it to match my precise table structures, but it returns everything I need and I now have an example to build future queries from. In my opinion, if someone is capable of learning there's nothing wrong with providing an example solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $GetRelations = "SELECT btr.RelationUID, btr.BlockTypeUID, btr.ChildBlockUID, 
     btr.Weight,bt.Name FROM block_type_relations btr
     INNER JOIN block_types bt ON bt.BlockTypeUID =btr.BlockTypeUID 
    WHERE BlockTypeUID = '$BlockTypeUID'";
```

Comment: I can't understand your comment@Doctus

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.